# Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

https://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/r5du4p6k/12/

If you long-press to drag, when you release you get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'

```
var t;
$(document).on('touchstart mousedown','.menu-item', function (event) {
    var self = this;
    if ($(self).hasClass('draggable')) return;
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        $(self).draggable({
            revert: true,
            helper: 'clone',
            opacity: .75,
            appendTo: 'body'
        }).draggable('enable').addClass('draggable');
        $(self).trigger(event)
    }, 800);
});

$(document).on("touchend mouseup", function () {
    clearTimeout(t);
    $('.draggable').draggable( 'disable' ).removeClass('draggable');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you duplicate the original element, when you try to remove the `draggable` - you also do it to the element you just duplicated (which is not draggable), so you can't `disable` it.

What you can do is disable it only on the first element:

```
$('.draggable').first().draggable( 'disable' ).removeClass('draggable');
```

Check this:
https://jsfiddle.net/r5du4p6k/13/

Comment: Oooh, the clone from the draggable event?  Makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using `.first()` I limited the scope with `$('#container .draggable')...`.  This seems to be more reliable.